# How do I run command line "explorer /n, /select,(filename)" in c++ builder?

Tags: shell, command-line, c++builder

I've tried shellexecute,  I've tried createprocess,  I can't seem to get this to do anything.

Running the command line manually (at the actual command prompt in a console window) works, but nothing I've tried so far will run it from within a c++ builder app.

Obviously (filename) is just a place holder.  It would be given a valid file name,  such as

explorer /n, /select,c:\123.doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using escaped backslashes in your filename? For example:;

```
"c:\123.doc"
```

should be:

```
"c:\\123.doc"
```

**Edit:**

```
  execlp("explorer", "/n, /select,c:\\foo.txt", 0)
```

works for me.

To avoid replacing the the current process, use **spawnlp** instead

Comment: The filename string is handled by built in file handling components so it is automatically implemented with double backslashes.  but neither types work.  I tried both.

Comment: Another thought - isn't it supposed to be a directory name, not a file name?

Comment: Your edit (execlp) worked for me.  Had to include the process header but that's not a problem.  Thanks!  I was tearing my hair out,  and I nearly had createprocess working when I decided to check back here.

Comment: On second thoughts.  execlp works except that it kills the calling process!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's someway to make `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute` work with this, but I suspect the simplest way to do this will be good old `system`, e.g. `system("explorer /n, /select,c:\\123.doc")`.

Just because it was bugging me, I went ahead and wrote a simple program that does this with CreateProcess:

```
 #define UNICODE
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <string>

 void SimpleWriteConsole(std::wstring msg) {
    DWORD written = 0;
    WriteConsole( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
          msg.c_str(), msg.length(), &written, NULL);
 }


 int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv, wchar_t **envp) {
    SimpleWriteConsole(L"Opening explorer...\n");
    std::wstring commandLine = L"explorer /n, /select,";
    if( argc < 2 ) {
       SimpleWriteConsole(L"Please include a file to select.\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    commandLine += argv[1];
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;

    if( ! CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<wchar_t*>(commandLine.c_str()), 
             NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &procInfo) ) {
       SimpleWriteConsole(L"Couldn't create process :(\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    CloseHandle( procInfo.hThread );
    CloseHandle( procInfo.hProcess );
    SimpleWriteConsole(L"Hooray launched explorer.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

It takes the C:\abc.txt part as a parameter on the command line. There's no extra dos box, and doesn't eat your existing process (exec is supposed to do that, btw) and it doesn't use a deprecated API.

Comment: Works,  but leaves a dos box open.  I'd rather not have that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, these replies have been useful but unfortunately they both have drawbacks which I would rather not have in my app...

`execlp()` causes the calling process to close.

`system()` shows a dos box which stays until I close the explorer window.

I am greatful for your your answers though.

I've got it to work with `winexec`.  Even though winexec's help file says this -

> Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
>   Windows. Applications should use the CreateProcess function.

I can't get `createprocess` to work, so I'm going to stick with `winexec` for now...

```
WinExec(String("explorer /n, /select,"+ FileName).c_str(),SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```